# when i load web service in nsdate and when i print nsdata im getting addresses of dats

Tags: cocoa, nsdata

```
NSString *loginURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/BookingTicketWebService/services/OfficeDetailsDAO"];


NSData *dataURL=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:loginURL]];

NSArray *responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:dataURL options:0 error:nil];
 NSLog(@"%@",dataURL);
```

//

when i print NSdata im Getting like this

```
<3c68313e 4f666669 63654465 7461696c 7344414f 3c2f6831 3e0a3c70 3e486920 74686572 652c2074 68697320 69732061 6e204158 49532073 65727669 6365213c 2f703e0a 3c693e50 65726861 70732074 68657265 2077696c 6c206265 20612066 6f726d20 666f7220 696e766f 6b696e67 20746865 20736572 76696365 20686572 652e2e2e 3c2f693e 0a>
```

Can u please sugest me im New to cocoa

Comment: you are printing NSData. thats why.

Answer (score 0):

NSData is not a string object.

If you want to print it out, you need to convert the NSData to a NSString.

e.g.:

```
NSString * stringFromData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: dataURL encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

also, as a FYI (for your information), "`dataURL`" is a really bad name for a NSData object.  Somebody else might be looking at your code and be easily confused, thinking it's a URL.  Better to use a nicer, more intuitive variable name.